# Estimation of time series using GARCH on Eviews

Tags: volatility, equities, garch, macro-economics, eviews

Firstly I should mention that I am new to both Eviews and GARCH models.

Anyway, I am conducting some research into the effect that different macroeconomic factors have had on stock index volatility from 2009 until 2020. Is there any way to include these macroeconomic time series when estimating the GARCH equation?

For example, say I am looking at the volatility of the S&P 500 and my macroeconomic variable is unemployment in America, how would I go about estimating this equation?

Thank you in advance,
L

Comment: Hi, you would be looking for the "GARCH X" model class or for "covariate GARCH". See for example here https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:676106/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have a read through that.